# Selecting Checkboxes in Groups with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to select certain checkboxes (think of a select all checkbox that checks other boxes). I am succesfully "checking" them but don't want to do them all. Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

Here is the jQuery. It is selecting every single checkbox when I need it to only select the checkboxes in that group. Since this ASP.NET is dynamic I have very little control over the HTML so I need to find and select what I need in the DOM as the objects appear. In other words, I can't add class names, id's, etc.

```
$(".anAlarmGroup input:first-child").click(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    //Select all alarms following this group heading until reaching the next group heading, while also grabbing each alarm ID
                    $('.anAlarm').find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked');

                }
                else {
                    $('.anAlarm').find('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
                }
            });
```

Comment: the jQuery you see here is doing what I am telling it to do in that it is finding all the instances of .anAlarmGroup, then finding all inputs with .anAlarm attached and checking them. I need it to ONLY do it for each .anAlarmGroup that is clicked. If you notice the image, this jQuery is selecting ALL of the checkboxes which is what I'm trying to avoid. Sorry--my question is cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.anAlarm').find('input:checkbox[name="whatever"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Or, in your case:

```
$(".anAlarmGroup input:first-child").click(function () {
    $('.anAlarm')
        .find('input:checkbox[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]')
        .prop('checked', ($(this).is(':checked')));
});
```

That should only check (or uncheck) the checkboxes with the same name.

Comment: To clarify, you group checkboxes the same way you group radio buttons, by setting their name attribute to all be the same.  So in this example `[name="whatever"]` checks all of the checkboxes that have the name attribute of "whatever"

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's difficult to come up with a surefire solution, however with JQuery you can use CSS style selectors to select DOM elements. You can use this to your advantage and select, for instance, only inputs that are a child of that particular fieldset if that fieldset has a unique class or ID. Or, if the fieldset doesn't have a unique ID you could select it bast on the :first-child selector of the form itself.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your click handler function you could use `$(this).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked');` or `$(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked');` depending how they are grouped. That will only look for elements at similar or deeper levels in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating the page dynamically, you can add class like so.  I created this method because I often add multiple css classes and wanted to simplify that.  So you just call AddCssClass(someControl,"anAlarmGroup")

```
public static void AddCssClass(WebControl control,string cssClass)
    {
      if (!control.CssClass.Contains(cssClass))
      {
        control.CssClass += (control.CssClass == String.Empty ? "" : " ") + cssClass;
      }
    }
```

Note that it will fail to add a css class if it is a sub string of another class such as adding "bold" if "bolditalic" already exists.